# Why is there random characters in my char array?

Tags: c

When I compile and run the following in C,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () 
{
    char func[16];
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(func); i++) {
        printf("Char %d in func is %c\n", i, func[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I get this:

```
Char 0 in func is P
Char 1 in func is 
Char 2 in func is @
Char 3 in func is 
Char 4 in func is 
Char 5 in func is 
Char 6 in func is 
Char 7 in func is 
Char 8 in func is p
Char 9 in func is 
Char 10 in func is @
Char 11 in func is 
Char 12 in func is 
Char 13 in func is 
Char 14 in func is 
Char 15 in func is
```

and when I compile at different times I get different random characters in my char array. I am guessing this is because it finds random ASCII characters in the memory of which the pointers were deleted but the actual information was left in the heap?

Should I bother setting everything to null in my array in a for loop or is there a function which does it?

Comment: Nothing here is on the heap

Comment: Undefined behavior for using the value of an object with automatic storage duration while it is indetermniate.

Comment: Uninitialised data is just that, uninitialised data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uninitialized local non-static variables, like your array `func`, haven an *indeterminate* value. Using them in any way without initialization leds to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

In reality the contents will be whatever happens to be in memory at the moment you run your program. It will be *seemingly* random.

Comment: shouldn't the compiler set uninitialized local non-static variables to 0? or at least, aren't some compilers that do?

Comment: @noob, There is no such requirement from the C standard.

Comment: @noob If a compiler is doing that, then it's doing something not specified in the C specification. It is however common for *debuggers* to do it when running the program, which can actually lead to the hiding of subtle bugs when it comes to pointers (pointers become `NULL` when running in the debugger, hiding the case when one is using an uninitialized pointer).

Comment: Okay I see. I didn't realize something as simple as func[16]=""; was gonna solve my problem. Always love the low-levelness about c.